# How to use "||" on select query laravel

Tags: laravel

I need help about my code.

I tried to make a code like that

```
$selectint = \DB::table('forums')->where([['category', '=', $f]])->orderByRaw('id ASC')->get();
```

but i'm need to make || function example in mysqli: 
`SELECT * FROM forums WHERE category = ? && (community = ? || community = ?) ORDER BY forum_id ASC`

Please.Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|| is an OR, so you could formulate it like

```
SELECT * 
FROM forums 
WHERE category = ? 
AND community IN (?, ?) 
ORDER BY forum_id ASC
```

In Eloquent (Laravel's ORM) it would be something like:

```
 $selectInt = \DB::table('forums')
   ->where('category', '=', $whatever)
   ->andWhereIn('community', [...])
   ->orderByRaw('id ASC')
   ->get();
```

Check out the official Laravel documentation about QueryBuilders: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to the where function

```
->where(function($query){ 
    $query->whereCommunity('this')
          ->orWhereCommunity('that');
    )})
```

Comment: Just to add, the official documentation has an example for 
 exactly this case: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping . In the example they write `select * from users where name = 'John' and (votes > 100 or title = 'Admin')` to the query builder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$selectint = DB::table('forums')->where('category','=','value')
->where(function($query){ 
     $query->where('community','=','C2')
      ->orWhere('community','=','C1');
})
->orderBy('forum_id')->get();
```

Comment:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'